# When trying to add a favorite in Application Insights, an error occurs, "Creating Application Insights 'Events logLevel and message' failed

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Looking for a way to solve this issue within Azure Application Insights when adding a favorite, additional information that is given:

The client xxxx@xx.com does not have authorization to perform action microsoft.insights/components/favorites/write  over scope subscription.

Obviously, permission needs to be granted but what permission and where? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you pls share more details on how to add a favorite? I haven't found any button to let me save a favorite in azure portal and I [found a place](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ca3b45e-99ec-4a04-898a-8e2d3d74b24b/manage-favorites-for-application-insights-gt-search?forum=ApplicationInsights) which said **Favorites is indeed being phased out**

Comment: @Tiny-wa Within the Overview area, across the top menu is : Application Dashboard - Getting Started - Search - Logs - Monitor resource group - Feedback - Favorites

Comment: Thanks sir, I had seen the button before, I mean that I can't create new favorites, because I haven't found the button to 'add favorite' or 'save as favorite'.

Comment: May I ask a question for why you need to add a favorite? If you just need to save a frequently used query?

Comment: @Tiny-wa It isn't a necessary need for a favorite as this is being done as a proof of concept to use Application Insights. To be honest, the interest is more in what permissions are needed to add favorites to help get a better understanding of what permissions are used in conjunction with Application Insights. It is part of a learning process and this just happened to be the first thing that popped up. My guess is that we would need a resource group with the specific permission(s) that allow for the favorite to be created and then add the user to that newly created resource group?

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I think you can assign Application Insights Component contributor role to the account. I've added the doc related to your case and you can try it. If it worked well, could you pls mark it as the answer?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on it and found [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control#select-a-role) may be helpful to you.

I think you could assign **Application Insights Component contributor** to the user. Pls follow the steps in the document.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I followed the doc and am testing out the solution. Will mark as the answer if all is good and again, thanks for your prompt replies.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , have a nice weekend~